# Pywinauto - How to select date from datepicker

Tags: python, automation, pywinauto

We need a help, we are automating a desktop base application using pywinauto.
We want to select date from the date picker (Calendar).

Could you please help us. Any solution or alternative code which is select the date from the calendar.

Comment: Alternative code to what? Do you have reference code? Can you post it in the question?

Comment: Alternative code for selecting date from the date control like 27-Apr-2018 or Today Date.    MyDate = window.Calendar
MyDate.Click(Today())     (Calendar is a object)

Answer (score 1):

How about [this unit test](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/pywinauto/unittests/test_common_controls.py#L1336)?

```
ctrl.set_time(
    year=2025,
    month=9,
    day_of_week=5,
    day=19,
    hour=1,
    minute=2,
    second=3,
    milliseconds=781
)
```

Or specifically [test_calendar.py](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/pywinauto/unittests/test_calendar.py):

```
app.Common_Controls_Sample.Calendar.set_current_date(2016, 4, 3, 13)
```

Answer (score 0):

Be my guest ;)

```
date_time_picker = get_child_by_properties(parent, {'class_name': 'SysDateTimePick32', 'control_id': ur control nr})

date_time_picker.set_time(date_time.year, date_time.month, date_time.weekday(), date_time.day, date_time.hour, date_time.minute, date_time.second, date_time.microsecond)
```

Comment: Please provide some context.